# Tesseract with PHP performance

Tags: php, zend-framework, tesseract

I have implemented an API with Laminas and Mezzio (former Zend Expressive). There I have a handler which uses the thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR library (https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php) to call Tesseract from PHP.

On my development environment everything works fine. Getting an image text by calling the API takes 2-6 seconds.

Now first I have deployed the API to a Google Cloud VM and now I have deployed it to a Raspberry Pi 4 4GB RAM model. Both are very slow! A request response takes 25-30 seconds. Tesseract doesn't seem to be the problem. If I call it from the CLI it is super fast. But simple API calls aren't slow either! It seems that the combination of Lamina / Mezzio with Tesseract is super slow. I really do nothing but extracting the text from the image and sending it back as a JSON response.

I am running php 7.3 on a apache2 server. The Pi is in my local network connected via LAN. I am testing the API calls with Postman.

What can I do to increase performance? Is it the hardware?

This is my handler code

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Handler;

use Laminas\Diactoros\Response\JsonResponse;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;
use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;

class OcrHandler implements RequestHandlerInterface
{
    public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request) : ResponseInterface
    {
        $measure = [];
        $start = microtime(true);

        $body = $request->getBody();

        $result = '';

        if(!empty($body->getContents())) {
            $measure['body_parse'] = microtime(true) - $start;
            $start = microtime(true);    

            $guid = $this->GUID();
            $imagePath = sprintf('%s/data/%s', getcwd(), $guid);

            file_put_contents($imagePath, $body->getContents());
            
            $measure['image_write'] = microtime(true) - $start;
            $start = microtime(true);

            $tesseractOcr = new TesseractOCR($imagePath);
            $tesseractOcr->withoutTempFiles();
            $result = $tesseractOcr->lang('deu')->run();
            
            $measure['image_parsing'] = microtime(true) - $start;
            $start = microtime(true);

            unlink($imagePath);

            $measure['image_delete'] = microtime(true) - $start;
        }

        return new JsonResponse(['result' => $result, 'measure' => $measure]);
    }

    private function GUID()
    {
        if (function_exists('com_create_guid') === true)
            return trim(com_create_guid(), '{}');
    
        return sprintf('%04X%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(16384, 20479), mt_rand(32768, 49151), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Ok so I've added time measurement and found the bottleneck. It is indeed the "image_parsing", the execution of Tesseract. Which for me, is strange, because as I said, on the CLI it's super fast. Here it takes most of the response time (27,9 sec)!

```
{
    "result": "...",
    "measure": {
        "body_parse": 0.0018658638000488281,
        "image_write": 0.0020492076873779297,
        "image_parsing": 27.909277200698853,
        "image_delete": 0.0005030632019042969
    }
}
```

Why is it so fast on the CLI but so slow when I call it from PHP? Is there any possible performance improvement?

Comment: Why not offload the resource from the user request and instead use a scheduler (cron) to scrape the data over a period of, say, 1 minute. Do you need the most up-to-date data instantly? Or is delivery of data instant more important? It is all down to your specifications.

Comment: @Jaquarh unfortunatelly I need the result as fast as possible. The API is called from another web app which allows customers to upload their invoices with automatic text recognition (total sum, tax amount, tax rate, etc.). Your idea could be a nice workaround if server costs would be too high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so as I already mentioned in my edit, the bottlebeck seems to be the image parsing. To be more specific, the bottleneck is the library "thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php". The following code, which uses the exec-function of PHP instead of the library takes 5,82 seconds (compared to 27,9 seconds). That's a huge difference. The following code works fine, assuming you've got tesseract installed on your machine:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Handler;

use Laminas\Diactoros\Response\JsonResponse;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;

class OcrHandler implements RequestHandlerInterface
{
    public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request) : ResponseInterface
    {
        $measure = [];
        $start = microtime(true);

        $body = $request->getBody();

        $result = '';

        if(!empty($body->getContents())) {
            $measure['body_parse'] = microtime(true) - $start;
            $start = microtime(true);    

            $guid = $this->GUID();
            $imagePath = sprintf('%s/data/%s', getcwd(), $guid);
            $outputPath = $imagePath . '_out';

            file_put_contents($imagePath, $body->getContents());
            
            $measure['image_write'] = microtime(true) - $start;
            $start = microtime(true);

            exec(sprintf('tesseract %s %s', $imagePath, $outputPath));
            $result = file_get_contents($outputPath . '.txt');
            
            $measure['image_parsing'] = microtime(true) - $start;
            $start = microtime(true);

            unlink($imagePath);
            unlink($outputPath . '.txt');

            $measure['image_delete'] = microtime(true) - $start;
        }

        return new JsonResponse(['result' => $result, 'measure' => $measure]);
    }

    private function GUID()
    {
        if (function_exists('com_create_guid') === true)
            return trim(com_create_guid(), '{}');
    
        return sprintf('%04X%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(16384, 20479), mt_rand(32768, 49151), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));
    }
}
```

You find a lot of recommendations for the thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php library on Stack Overflow but you should check your performance! On my dev machine it worked fine, but on production it's super slow and production is a question of cost.